# How to update complex type field (json) using ormLite from servicestack

Tags: postgresql, ormlite-servicestack

I am trying to update only one column with jsonb type. Insert works perfectly without any surprises but I can't find out how can I do update only one field with attribute [ComplextType('json')]
db.UpdateOnly(() => new QuestionPoco() {Answers = requestDto.answers},
                        where: q => q.Id.ToString() == question.id.ToString());

Answer (score 2):

This should now be supported from [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/commit/1a9cbad01015ce0a20c947cee742ff81e6a464da) which is now [available on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/commit/1a9cbad01015ce0a20c947cee742ff81e6a464da).

We've also added new typed [PgSqlTypes Attributes](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.OrmLite.PostgreSQL/PgsqlTypes.cs) which you can use instead of `[CustomField("json")]`, e.g:

```
public class Question
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }

    //equivalent to: [CustomField("json")]
    [PgSqlJson]
    public List<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
}

public class Answer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Which you can Insert/Update as normal, e.g:

```
db.DropAndCreateTable<Question>();

var createTableSql = db.GetLastSql();
Assert.That(createTableSql, Does.Contain("\"answers\" json NULL"));

db.Insert(new Question
{
    Id = 1,
    Answers = new List<Answer>
    {
        new Answer { Id = 1, Text = "Q1 Answer1" }
    }
});

var question = db.SingleById<Question>(1);
Assert.That(question.Answers.Count, Is.EqualTo(1));
Assert.That(question.Answers[0].Text, Is.EqualTo("Q1 Answer1"));

db.UpdateOnly(() => new Question {
        Answers = new List<Answer> { new Answer { Id = 1, Text = "Q1 Answer1 Updated" } }
    },
    @where: q => q.Id == 1);

question = db.SingleById<Question>(1);
Assert.That(question.Answers[0].Text, Is.EqualTo("Q1 Answer1 Updated"));
```

Comment: any ideas when it will be available for nuget and for .net core?